# fadeOut / fadeIn div according to multiscroll active element

Tags: jquery, multiscroll.js

I'm trying to fadeIn the `.hello` div when other than the first element is active and fadeOut when the first element is active.

Multiscroll.js add automatically the active class.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/oadfcjt2/7/

```
<div class="hello">HELLO</div>

<div id="myContainer">

    <div class="ms-left">
        <div class="ms-section firstelement" id="left1">
             <h1>Left 1 </h1>
        </div>

        <div class="ms-section" id="left2">
            <h1>Left 2 </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ms-right">
        <div class="ms-section firstelement" id="right1">
            <h1>Right 1</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="ms-section" id="right2">
            <h1>Right 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/multiscroll.js#afterload-anchorlink-index), you could use `afterLoad` callback.
Start your `hello` div hidden in css:

```
.hello {
    ...
    display: none
}
```

and then with jQuery, `fadeIn()` or `fadeOut()` according to visible index (starting at 1):

```
$('#myContainer').multiscroll({
    sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
    menu: false,

    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        if (index == 1)
            $('.hello').fadeOut('slow');
        else
            $('.hello').fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```